# Prevent drag scrolling in Safari on Mac

Tags: javascript, html, css, macos, safari

Take a look at [this codepen](https://codepen.io/NeXTs/pen/dyRXjbE)
There's red square in the corner.
[image]
If you click (using mouse or touchpad) this square and drag it down - in Safari on Mac `.parent` element will scroll down.
**Even though .parent has `overflow-y: hidden;`**

[image]

**No scrolling occurs in all other browsers.**
How can I prevent this scrolling on safari?
As a rough solution, I can listen to the scroll and override the scrollTop if it's not zero, but perhaps there is a more elegant solution?

Comment: Hi Denis, please see my solution when you have a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely an interesting find! You'd think this would be impossible since you set `overflow-y` to `none`. Nonetheless you can prevent this behavior and disallow clicks inside the parent using this JavScript:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
parent.addEventListener('mousedown', e => e.preventDefault());
```

By adding `preventDefault()` to the event triggered on `mousedown`, you prevent the browser from evaluating any further events related to that click, including dragging. Here it is in action:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
parent.addEventListener('mousedown', e => e.preventDefault());
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.child {
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, red, tomato), linear-gradient(to bottom, white, black);
  background-size: 50px 50px, 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks, this is a good solution, better than checking and overriding scrollTop. Let's wait a few more days, if there are no better ideas, I will accept this answer.

Comment: @Denis thanks! Let me know if there's anything else specifically you're looking for which I can add, or are you just waiting to see if there's a CSS-only solution to this? I too would be very interested to see one.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an intermediary div. then, set width, height, overflow properties to it.

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

/** intermediary div */
.parent > div {
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  width: 100%; /** this should be 100% **/
  height: 200%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, red, tomato), linear-gradient(to bottom, white, black);
  background-size: 50px 50px, 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or add `pointer-events:none` to parent.

```css
.parent {
  /* This prevents dragging */
  pointer-events: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.child {
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, red, tomato), linear-gradient(to bottom, white, black);
  background-size: 50px 50px, 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice find with first solution, hacky but almost css-only.

Comment: I corrected a typo `pointer-event` ➞ `pointer-events` for the second solution. The second solution still does not appear to work for me, but the first is very good. One thing I like most about your first solution is that is does not actually prevent drag-scrolling on the x-axis, but only drag-scrolling outside the frame, the y-axis in this case. Well done.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for pointing out! the second solution doesn't work, Because I've pointer-events: auto to child. I've removed it now. This can be used if there is no interactions required for the descendants

Answer (score 0):

Using css you can give pointer-events:none; to avoid any events occurring while clicking it.

Comment: I need it to scroll horizontally, that's why there is an overflow-x: auto in the example